# Html <img> not loading image even tougth they're in tha same directory

Tags: html, django

my code is like that:

```
<body>

<a href = "{% url 'pacientes' %}">
    <img src="/aaa.png"/>
</a>
</body>
```

my question is: Why does the image not load if the image and the html are in the same directory

obs.:

i already tried write the img tag out of the 'a' tag too.
this html is part of a django project, idk if this really make difference

Comment: The forward slash tells the program to look up to the main directory folder, so if that's not where you are looking for the image, remove the forward slash from the fron of the image name

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: i tried to change to ./aaa.png and the problem stills

Comment: and to aaa.png and don't worked too

Answer (score 1):

Load `static` in your template

```
{% load static %}
<body>

<a href = "{% url 'pacientes' %}">
    <img src="{% static 'my_app/aaa.png' %}"/>
</a>
</body>
```

See also: [Configuring static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
 <img src="aaa.png"/>
```

Comment: Did you make the configuration for static files?